# Can I read Pdf file without downloading it on Local Machine with Selenium or other C# Libraries

Tags: c#, selenium, pdf, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want to read pdf data in String or in stream object without downloading it on local machine through some C# library. Currently I am working on a Automation project where I am using Selenium-chromewebdriver
Please suggest a C# Library from which I can achieve this task.

Comment: Refer pdfbox - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pdfbox/

Comment: How can I read pdf directly without downloading?

Comment: You can open that pdf in browser

Comment: After open I need that pdf data in string or in stream object. Can you please suggest any library for this? thanks

Comment: yes thats pdfbox or iTextSharp , read it,- https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/5.5.13

Comment: it's didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to use this solution in your projects, you need to do the following steps:

Add references to itextsharp.dll and SharpZiplib.dll
Add the PDFParser.cs class to your project

Then you can use the newly added class in the following way:

```
// create an instance of the pdfparser class
PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();

// extract the text
String result = pdfParser.ExtractText(pdfFile);
```

Using iTextSharp's PdfReader class to extract the deflated content of every page, I use a simple function ExtractTextFromPDFBytes to extract the text contents from the deflated page.

Comment: Yes I know. I just wanted to know that which Library should I use for read pdf in string  or stream object without downloading it on local machine.

Comment: @Kiran, when you extract the text you already got the file, don't you?